# How can I use the firebase auth services in my js file of my web hosted on firebase hosting?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a web page hosted on firebase hosting, then in my `index.html` added the URLs reserved for Auth, Realtime Database and Storage services as specified in the documentation. I followed the steps by running the `firebase init` and `firebase deploy` commands on my terminal. Everything seems to be fine, my page is on the internet and I have no faults in the browser console.

My question is how can I edit a js file and use for example `firebase.auth()`, do I have to initialize firebase in my js file, initialize it from the index.html or do something before I can write code and use the installed services?

Comment: This might help https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls

Comment: The instructions for using Firebase Auth don't really change if you're using Firebase Hosting.  If you are having a specific problem or error, please edit the question to illustrate what you're running into.